# Apache Flink stops reading file after restoring job from checkpoint/savepoint

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job, one task of which continuously reads a file on S3 in a pretty straightforward fashion:

```scala
val environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val path = "s3://my-bucket/my-folder/my-file.json"

val rules = environment
  .readFile(
      new Input(new Path(path)),
      path,
      FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
      60000L // check for updates every minute
     )
...

class Input(path: Path) extends DelimitedInputFormat[Schema](path, null) {
  this.setDelimiter("0xff")

  override def readRecord(reuse:  Array[Byte], bytes: Array[Byte], offset: Int, numBytes: Int): Array[Byte] = {
    bytes.slice(offset, numBytes))
  }
}
```

When I start the job, it works as expected - it reads the file on startup and after that it checks every 60 seconds if file was changed.

The problem starts when I restart the job from a checkpoint/savepoint: the job no longer reads the file on startup neither it can monitor the changes of this file.

I tried to use the whole folder on S3 - no luck

```scala
val path = "s3://my-bucket/my-folder"
```

I'm running this job on Kubernetes with [Flink Kubernetes Operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/) and use standard `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.17.0.jar` Flink's Hadoop filesystem plugin to read from s3.
version of Flink 1.17

what am I missing?